# Get attribute names of a model that doesn't have any records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there any way I can fetch all attribute names for a model that doesn't have any records yet?

For example, a company `'App\Company'` has a name, address and email address. However, there are currently no company records stored on the database. Without accessing any existing records in the database, I wish to return the array

```
[
    0 => 'name',
    1 => 'address',
    2 => 'email_address'
]
```

I have tried the following:

```
$class = 'App\Company';
return array_keys((new $class)->getAttributes());
```

But this returns an empty array, as the fields are all empty.

Is there any way I can get these without searching the database for an existing record?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DB facade to get a table metadata

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB
...
DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('tableName'); //table name not model name
```

You can test it in tinker this way:

```
$ php artisan tinker
Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('Users');
```

output:

```
[
 "id",
 "name",
 "email",
 "password",
 "remember_token",
 "created_at",
 "updated_at",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attributes from the database directly. Assuming your company model has a corresponding table called companys or something similar then

```
$attributeArray = Schema::getColumnListing('companys'); 
dd($attributeArray);
```

Will give you the output you require. Only problem being it doesn't show any custom attributes of your model.